# How to replace this change this javascript code so that you can change the current date

Tags: javascript

So I have this code. Its very simple. I input my birthday the the day, month and year. Press the CALCULATE Button and it will immediately tell me below how many days I have lived.

Now I want to change it so that I can also input the current date to compare with my birth date.

How do I do this?

Please and thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calculate My Birthday</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<label>Birth Day</label>
<input type="text" value="0" id="bday" onClick="javascript:SetDay(document.getElementById('bmonth').value, document.getElementById('byear').value);" />
<label>Birth Month</label>
<input type="text" value="0" id="bmonth" onClick="javascript:SetMonth();" />
<label>Birth Year</label>
<input type="text" value="0" id="byear" size="4" />
<input type="button" value="CALCULATE" onclick="calculate()">
<div>You've been living for ( <span id="days"></span> ) days</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetDay(month, year) {
  var lastDay = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
  var nDay = document.getElementById("bday").value;
  if (nDay > lastDay) {
    nDay = 1;
  }
  document.getElementById("bday").value = nDay;
}

function SetMonth(from_SetMonth = false) {
  var nMonth = document.getElementById("bmonth").value;
  if (nMonth == 13) {
    nMonth = 1;
  }
  document.getElementById("bmonth").value = nMonth;
}

function isValidDate(s) {
  var bits = s.split('/');
  var y = bits[0],
    m = bits[1],
    d = bits[2];
  // Assume not leap year by default (note zero index for Jan)
  var daysInMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

  // If evenly divisible by 4 and not evenly divisible by 100,
  // or is evenly divisible by 400, then a leap year
  if ((!(y % 4) && y % 100) || !(y % 400)) {
    daysInMonth[1] = 29;
  }
  return d <= daysInMonth[--m]
}

function days_between(date1, date2) {

  // The number of milliseconds in one day
  var ONE_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24

  // Convert both dates to milliseconds
  var date1_ms = date1.getTime()
  var date2_ms = date2.getTime()

  // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
  var difference_ms = Math.abs(date1_ms - date2_ms)

  // Convert back to days and return
  return Math.round(difference_ms / ONE_DAY)

}

function calculate() {
  var _bd = document.getElementById('byear').value + "/" + document.getElementById('bmonth').value + "/" + document.getElementById('bday').value;
  if (!isValidDate(_bd)) return;
  var _days = days_between(new Date(), new Date(_bd));
  document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = _days;
}

var cDate = new Date();
var cDay = cDate.getDate();
var cMonth = cDate.getMonth();
var cYear = cDate.getFullYear();
var days_gone = 0;

++cMonth;

document.getElementById("bday").value = cDay;
document.getElementById("bmonth").value = cMonth;
document.getElementById("byear").value = cYear;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you want another input which is use for comparison ?

Comment: In this line `var _days = days_between(new Date(), new Date(_bd));` the `new Date()` is the current time, i.e. today. Substitute that with the day you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use input `type="date"` to display calendar to the user, where user can select his/her birth date.

```
<label for="bdate">Choose your bday</label>
<input type="date" id="bdate">
```

And then you can calculate the difference.

```
var _bday = document.getElementById('bdate').value;
var _days = days_between(new Date(), new Date(_bday));
```

```js
 function SetDay(month, year) {
  var lastDay = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
  var nDay = document.getElementById("bday").value;
  if (nDay > lastDay) {
    nDay = 1;
  }
  document.getElementById("bday").value = nDay;
}

function SetMonth(from_SetMonth = false) {
  var nMonth = document.getElementById("bmonth").value;
  if (nMonth == 13) {
    nMonth = 1;
  }
  document.getElementById("bmonth").value = nMonth;
}

function isValidDate(s) {
  var bits = s.split('/');
  var y = bits[0],
    m = bits[1],
    d = bits[2];
  // Assume not leap year by default (note zero index for Jan)
  var daysInMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

  // If evenly divisible by 4 and not evenly divisible by 100,
  // or is evenly divisible by 400, then a leap year
  if ((!(y % 4) && y % 100) || !(y % 400)) {
    daysInMonth[1] = 29;
  }
  return d <= daysInMonth[--m]
}

function days_between(date1, date2) {

  // The number of milliseconds in one day
  var ONE_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24

  // Convert both dates to milliseconds
  var date1_ms = date1.getTime()
  var date2_ms = date2.getTime()

  // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
  var difference_ms = Math.abs(date1_ms - date2_ms)

  // Convert back to days and return
  return Math.round(difference_ms / ONE_DAY)

}

function calculate() {
  var _bd = document.getElementById('byear').value + "/" + document.getElementById('bmonth').value + "/" + document.getElementById('bday').value;
  
  var _bday = document.getElementById('bdate').value;
  if (!isValidDate(_bd)) return;
  var _days = days_between(new Date(), new Date(_bday));
  document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = _days;
}

var cDate = new Date();
var cDay = cDate.getDate();
var cMonth = cDate.getMonth();
var cYear = cDate.getFullYear();
var days_gone = 0;

++cMonth;

document.getElementById("bday").value = cDay;
document.getElementById("bmonth").value = cMonth;
document.getElementById("byear").value = cYear;
```

```html
<label>current Day</label>
<input type="text" value="0" id="bday" onClick="javascript:SetDay(document.getElementById('bmonth').value, document.getElementById('byear').value);" /><br>
<label>current Month</label>
<input type="text" value="0" id="bmonth" onClick="javascript:SetMonth();" /><br>
<label>current Year</label>
<input type="text" value="0" id="byear" size="4" /><br>
<label for="bdate">Choose your bday</label>
<input type="date" id="bdate"><br>
<input type="button" value="CALCULATE" onclick="calculate()">
<div>You've been living for ( <span id="days"></span> ) days</div>
```